# Using Action Mailer and ROR3 to send an email on the creation of user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to follow section 2.1 of [this tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#walkthrough-to-generating-a-mailer)

When I create a new user, I just get this message:

```
NameError in UsersController#create

uninitialized constant UsersController::UserMailer
```

I've had a break from ROR, and now I've found I've forgotten quite a lot!

What are the most likely causes of this error?

My mailer (controller): app/mailers/usermailer.rb:

```
class Usermailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url = 'http://example.com/login'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to my awesome site')
  end
end
```

My view: app/usermailer/welcome_email.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to example.com, <%= @user.name %></h1>
    <p>
      You have successfully signed up to example.com,
      your username is: <%= @user.login %>.<br/>
    </p>
    <p>
      To login to the site, just follow this link: <%= @url %>.
    </p>
    <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
  </body>
</htm>
```

Not sure what this is classed as. A "view call" in the users controller to the view welcome_email to @user:

```
   UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
```

Here it is in context at app/controllers/users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/new
  # GET /users/new.json
  def new
    @user = User.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
```

## #

```
    # send welcome email after save
    UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
```

## #

```
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /users/1
  # PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can you please try server restart?

Comment: Yep. That didn't do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing your capitalization up a little. You should use `UserMailer` (with a capital 'M') to refer to the constant (a.k.a. class) and `user_mailer` for the file and directory names.

So for your mailer, the file name should be `app/mailers/user_mailer.rb` and then use:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
```

to define the class.

You'll also need to put the view for the mailer at `app/views/user_mailer/welcome_email.html` instead of `app/usermailer/welcome_email.html.erb`.

What Rails was trying to tell you from that error message (uninitialized constant UsersController::UserMailer) is that the UsersController can't find a constant called `UserMailer` anywhere. It checked in the load paths for a file with file name `user_mailer.rb` but couldn't find it because your file wasn't snake-cased properly. Had you fixed that, alone, then next it would have complained that it expected `user_mailer.rb` to define the `UserMailer` constant. The way rails does this is:

```
# First, going from the constant to the file name to look for:
UserMailer.name.underscore  # => 'user_mailer'

# Now, going from the file name to the expected constant defined in that file:
'user_mailer`.classify  # => 'UserMailer'
'UserMailer'.constantize  # => UserMailer
```